# How do I run selected modules using parent pom in Maven like I have

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, maven-plugin, maven-3, maven-scm

```
<module>APP_1</module>
<module>web_1</module>
<module>service_1</module>
<module>schema_1</module>

<module>APP_2</module>
<module>web_2</module>
<module>service_2</module>
<<module>schema_2</module>
```

sometimes as developer if I want to build first module with all it's depedecies only so how should I achieve this task in parent pom?
maven 3.0.3
jdk-1.6

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-pl` or `--projects` parameter of maven command-line for this.

e.g.

```
mvn --p APP_1
```

This will build `APP_1` and its dependant modules.

Answer (score 2):

Use profile in parent pom:

```
</profiles>
  <profile>
    <!-- Build App 1 -->
    <id>app1</id>
    <modules>
      <module>APP_1</module>
      <module>web_1</module>
      <module>service_1</module>
      <module>schema_1</module>
    </modules>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <!-- Build App 2 -->
    <id>app2</id>
    <modules>
      <module>APP_2</module>
      <module>web_2</module>
      <module>service_2</module>
      <<module>schema_2</module>
    </modules>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

To build App1:

> mvn clean install -Papp1

To build App2:

> mvn clean install -Papp2